# Calculate matrix means and compile across matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I've only been using R for about a week (converting long-time SAS user). I'm running a model that generates multiple identical matrices (representing different parameter scenarios) similarly to the simplified example below:

```
    library(matrixStats)
    len<-50
    wid<-10
    mat1 <- matrix(nrow=len, ncol=wid)
    mat2 <- matrix(nrow=len, ncol=wid)
    mat3 <- matrix(nrow=len, ncol=wid)
set.seed(123)    
for (i in 1:wid){
      for (n in 1:len){
        mat1[n,i] <- runif(1)
        mat2[n,i] <- runif(1)
        mat3[n,i] <- runif(1)
    }}
```

I want to calculate the mean and standard deviation of the column sums for each matrix independently, similar to:

```
a <- colSums(mat1)
mean(a)
sd(a)
```

repeated for each matrix and then compile those values into a single dataset with a matrix identifier, mean, and standard deviation, similar to:

```
mat1_ID    24.42858    2.198454
mat2_ID    25.67452    1.677669
mat3_ID    24.31933    1.572029
```

I have no idea how to do this in R. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, the code displayed here does not make use of the 'matrixStats' package, so no need to use `library(matrixStats)` here.  The `colSums()` function comes from the 'base' package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mats <- paste0("mat", 1:3)
t(sapply(mats, function(x) {
  cs <- colSums(get(x))
  c(mean(cs), sd(cs))
}))

         [,1]     [,2]
mat1 24.42858 2.198454
mat2 25.67452 1.677669
mat3 24.31933 1.572029
```

Comment: Another (possibly confusing) option `funs <- list(sd=sd, mean=mean); sapply(funs, mapply, lapply(mget(paste0("mat", 1:3)), colSums))`

Comment: Thanks...this worked great! I particularly like the paste0 function, as I have many matrices with sequentially increasing file names and this will keep me from having to type them all individually. If I had sets of matrices with different file prefixes (e.g, mat1, mat2, mat3, test1, test2, test3) could I similarly combine them all using this function?

Comment: @JackHandy: Sure, for example: `paste0(c("mat", "test"), rep(1:3, each = 2))`

Answer (score 1):

If you want speed you can try my way. I will use **package *Rfast***. Since you are new in R I will show step by step my example.

```
install.packages("Rfast") # download package Rfast
```

I will use the matrices from your example.

```
mats <- list(mat1=mat1,mat2=mat2,mat3=mat3) # "mat=mat" store matrix mat and add name
result <- sapply(mats,function(x){
             s <- Rfast::colsums(x) # you can use also the parallel version using argument "parallel"
             c(sd=Rfast::Var(s,std=TRUE),mean=mean(s))
          })

result # this will print the matrix    
      mat1      mat2      mat3
sd    1.677669  1.677669  1.572029
mean 25.674519 25.674519 24.319328
```

You can transpose the matrix to get the result as you wish

```
t(result)
           sd     mean
mat1 1.677669 25.67452
mat2 1.677669 25.67452
mat3 1.572029 24.31933
```

Comment: The code wouldn't work for me. Is there something missing in the mean command?

Comment: Yes and sorry for that. There was a type but I have edited my answer and test again.

Comment: Great...thanks! I found two other typos: in the list statement, it should be mat1=mat1 (which is why the mat1 and mat2 result values were identical in your example), and there's a right parentheses missing after the mean command (there should be 3). I'm not sure what the speed difference is between the two methods with this simple example, but I'll see what happens with my larger matrices.

Comment: Thanks for you comments. I have edit again the answer. Yes, my answer is more for the speed part because you might need it if your matrices are large. Especially for var which might crash for large matrices.